# Snap apps stop working after kernel updated

Tags: snap

After a full system update/upgrade most of my snap apps stopped working and while for some reason 2 apps work others don't. Can some one advise?

```
$ orangecalc
udev_enumerate_scan failed
$ corebird
udev_enumerate_scan failed
$ smalltextpad
udev_enumerate_scan failed
$ codebreakers
udev_enumerate_scan failed
```

I already un-installed and re-installed them and nothing seem to work.

```
$ snap list
Name               Version                   Rev   Developer       Notes
codebreakers       1.05                      x1                    devmode
core               16-2.27.6+git362.c2cddc4  2883  canonical       core
corebird           1.5.1                     40    snapcrafters    -
gping              0+git.f7e3cea             13    orf             -
keepassxc          2.2.0                     23    keepassxreboot  -
notes              0.9.0~gitb6e3b34          4     notes-developers  -
orangecalc         1.5.8                     3     gcclinux        -
smalltextpad       1.1.0                     1     gcclinux        -

$ snap refresh
All snaps up to date.
```

Comment: What is the output of ```snap version```?

Comment: $ snap version
snap    2.28~rc2
snapd   2.28~rc2
series  16
ubuntu  16.04
kernel  4.4.0-93-generic

Comment: Also noticed if I delete (snap remove app) re-install has no effect, if I snap remove app, then reboot and then snap install app it works once, close the app open again and i have the same problem.

Comment: The [thread here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/weird-udev-enumerate-error/2360/18) implies that this issue stems from a bug relating to the nvidia drivers; it should be fixed in the latest beta 2.28.5, which one can obtain with `sudo snap refresh core --beta` (may later be undone with `sudo snap revert core`). I can't confirm since my snap app is currently working, after having removed it, restarted my machine, then re-installed it (following your advice).